# How to create a signature in python using an api key and timestamp, with sha256 hex encryption

Tags: python, api, digital-signature, sha256

This is the sample code provided within the api documentation:

```
#!/bin/bash 
apiKey="yourApiKey"
secret="yourSecret"
curl -i \
-X GET \
-H 'Accept:application/json' \
-H 'Api-key:'$apiKey'' \
-H 'X-Signature:'$(echo -n ${apiKey}${secret}$(date +%s)|sha256sum|awk '{ print $1}')'' \
https://api.test.hotelbeds.com/hotel-api/1.0/status
```

This is what I am doing in python:

```
secret = b"Secret key"
apikey = b"Api key"
datenow = str(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp())
datenow = bytes(datenow, 'utf-8')

sig = apikey + secret + datenow

hash = hashlib.sha256(sig).hexdigest()
```

However, I am getting an authentication error. Can someone please help me fix my code?

Comment: Just use strings instead of bytes?

Comment: @BryceWayne I tried that too but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved by converting the date into and int and then into str.

Answer (score 0):

import hashlib, time

string= str(API_KEY).strip()+str(SECRET).strip()+str(int(time.time())).strip()

signature= hashlib.sha256(string.encode()).hexdigest()

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.